# Is there a way to convert/deploy a python project based on mediapipe and opencv on android?

Tags: python, android, opencv, kivy, mediapipe

I have made a pose estimation project using mediapipe and opencv in python. How can I convert or deploy it on android devices by using tools like Beeware/Chaquopy, or recode the whole thing in Kivy?
I am open to suggestions on changes in the project to incorporate it in android.

Comment: Unfortunately [Mediapipe isn't currently supported by Chaquopy](https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy/issues/479), and I don't think it's supported by any of the other Python frameworks you mentioned either. If you want to use Mediapipe on Android, the easiest way would be use its official Android support in Java or Kotlin.

Comment: Any update? Have you managed to use mediapipe with Kivy on Android?